# How to group inside a JS map function

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have some data coming from the DB:

```
{InteractionDate: '2022-07-07', Time: 10, ID: 'eac61b7e-8e25-4445-ad1d-f1ee8c6ac86c'}
{InteractionDate: '2022-07-07', Time: 20, ID: 'c3a78dbe-553d-4ecc-b4ef-8d8d3039c521'}
{InteractionDate: '2022-07-07', Time: 33, ID: 'c3a78dbe-553d-4ecc-b4ef-8d8d3039c521'}
{InteractionDate: '2022-07-07', Time: 30, ID: '229530ed-ca44-4015-b1d7-b528be5b6071'}
```

and I need to show it in the UI like so:

```
Month   Time    # of Unique ID's
=====   ====    ================
07/22   93      3
```

The ID's is a new addition that I need some help with. Right now, I'm using this to group all the dates and sum the times.

```
        const groupedArray = _(allInteractions)
        .groupBy(v => moment(v.InteractionDate).format('MM/YYYY'))
        .map((item, date) => ({
            interactionDate: date,
            totalSec: _.sumBy(item, 'Time')
            //uniqueIDs:    ?
        }))
        .value();
```

The question is - How do I know how many DIFFERENT id's were seen in 07/22?

Comment: I don't think `.groupBy()` is a built-in JavaScript method (wish it was though).

Comment: this is lodash from what i see

Comment: Yea, should've added lodash as tag. Thanks Konrad for doing that

Comment: @zer00ne btw `group` is at experimental stage. hope it gets through

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is not that pretty, but it's working

```js
var allInteractions = get_data();
const groupedArray = _(allInteractions)
  .groupBy(v => moment(v.InteractionDate).format('MM/YYYY'))
  .map(function(item, date) {
    var obj = {}
    item.forEach(function(item) {
      obj[item.ID] = true
    });
    return {
      interactionDate: date,
      totalSec: _.sumBy(item, 'Time'),
      uniqueIDs: Object.keys(obj).length
    }
  })
  .value();

console.log(groupedArray)

function get_data() {
  return [{
      InteractionDate: '2022-07-07',
      Time: 10,
      ID: 'eac61b7e-8e25-4445-ad1d-f1ee8c6ac86c'
    },
    {
      InteractionDate: '2022-07-07',
      Time: 20,
      ID: 'c3a78dbe-553d-4ecc-b4ef-8d8d3039c521'
    },
    {
      InteractionDate: '2022-07-07',
      Time: 33,
      ID: 'c3a78dbe-553d-4ecc-b4ef-8d8d3039c521'
    },
    {
      InteractionDate: '2022-07-07',
      Time: 30,
      ID: '229530ed-ca44-4015-b1d7-b528be5b6071'
    },
    {
      InteractionDate: '2022-05-05',
      Time: 30,
      ID: '229530ed-ca44-4015-b1d7-b528be5b6071'
    }
  ];

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you! At this point prettiness is less important ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a vanilla JS way to do it using the built-in `Set` operator.

```js
const data = [{InteractionDate: '2022-07-07', Time: 10, ID: 'eac61b7e-8e25-4445-ad1d-f1ee8c6ac86c'},
{InteractionDate: '2022-07-07', Time: 20, ID: 'c3a78dbe-553d-4ecc-b4ef-8d8d3039c521'},
{InteractionDate: '2022-07-07', Time: 33, ID: 'c3a78dbe-553d-4ecc-b4ef-8d8d3039c521'},
{InteractionDate: '2022-07-07', Time: 30, ID: '229530ed-ca44-4015-b1d7-b528be5b6071'}]

const result = data.reduce((acc, el) => {
  if (!acc[el.InteractionDate]) {
    acc[el.InteractionDate] = { time: 0, ids: new Set() }
  }
  acc[el.InteractionDate].time += el.Time;
  acc[el.InteractionDate].ids.add(el.ID);
  return acc;
}, {});

Object.entries(result).forEach(([date, { time, ids }]) => {
  console.log({date, time, ids: ids.size });
})
```